# Conditionally altering a dataframe column based on another column's values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following pandas dataframe `d1`:

```
+----------+-------+---------+--------------+
| Item Num | Cost  | Revenue |  Rev / Cost  |
+----------+-------+---------+--------------+
|        1 | 45.76 |  345.67 | 7.5539772727 |
|        2 | 55.78 |  456.92 | 8.1914664754 |
|        3 | 34.68 |       0 |            0 |
|        4 | 79.85 |       0 |            0 |
+----------+-------+---------+--------------+
```

What I would like is for the values of the `Cost / Rev` column to be equal to the `Cost` for that row, multiplied by negative 1, in cases where the 'Cost / Rev' is equal to 0.

So the desired output would be:

```
+----------+-------+---------+--------------+
| Item Num | Cost  | Revenue |  Rev / Cost  |
+----------+-------+---------+--------------+
|        1 | 45.76 |  345.67 | 7.5539772727 |
|        2 | 55.78 |  456.92 | 8.1914664754 |
|        3 | 34.68 |       0 |       -34.68 |
|        4 | 79.85 |       0 |       -79.85 |
+----------+-------+---------+--------------+
```

What I have so far is:

```
d1['Rev / Cost'] = d1['Rev / Cost'].apply(lambda x: x if x > 0 else d1['Cost'])
```

Which simply overwrites the intended range with a single value and throws the following warning:

```
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a mask and then use `loc` to assign to a subslice.

```
mask = df['Rev / Cost'] == 0
df.loc[mask, 'Rev / Cost'] = df.loc[mask, 'Cost'].mul(-1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since booleans evaluate to 0/1, you can simply multiply the condition by the Cost and subtract it from Rev / Cost. This gives a nice performance boost.

```
df['Rev / Cost'] -=  df['Cost'] * (df['Rev / Cost'] == 0)
```

You can also use `np.where`

```
df['Rev / Cost'] = np.where(df['Rev / Cost'] == 0, -df['Cost'], df['Rev / Cost']
```

Or `Series.where`

```
df['Rev / Cost'] = df['Rev / Cost'].where(lambda x: x != 0, df.Cost)
```